# Ambiguous conversion - C++

Tags: c++, numbers, type-conversion

I'm trying to code a function using C++ and Xcode as compiler that will test if a is palindrome or not. The code works well when the argument is a "C++ born" type (such as int, long, double etc.) but I want to use the function for larger values. So I used an argument of type [BigInteger](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/). But the compiler gives an error on the line

```
 BigInteger q = x - floor(x.toLong()/10)*10
```

saying that `Conversion from 'double' to 'const BigInteger' is ambiguous`. Here is the whole code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BigInteger.hh"

using namespace std;
bool isPalindrom(BigInteger x){
long ch = ceil(log10(x.toUnsignedLong())), n[ch];
//    cout << floor(log10(x)) + 1 << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= ch; i++){
    BigInteger q = x - floor(x.toLong()/10)*10;
    n[i] = q.toInt();
    //        cout << n[i] << endl;
    x /= 10;
}

for (long i = 0; i <= ceil(ch); i++){
    if (n[i] != n[ch - i]){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is not the whole code, you did not show your `BigInteger.hh` header file, which might be faulty....

Comment: FYI "C++ born" types are called PODs (plain old datatypes).

Comment: I'm going to assume that BigInteger doesn't have a built in cast type here, but has a conversion function instead?  Haven't used that one yet...

Comment: Call me names, but I'd actually render that number to string and then compare with loop from both ends.

Comment: What conversions does BigInteger support?

Comment: You don't get any benefit from `class BigInteger` if you're just going to access it using `toLong()` or `toUnsignedLong()`.  And yes, there is no conversion from `double` to `BigInteger`, for good reasons.

Comment: The `BigInteger.hh` file is in the link. It's a downloadable library. And there is no way that I can do this operation?

Comment: @H2CO3 Not quite. A class can be a POD (and the term is most commonly associated with classes). See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c . "Fundamental type" is probably the term you're looking for.

Comment: @JonBentley Isn't `class` a C++-specific kind of type? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I haven't yet encountered a flavour of C that had classes (except Objective-C of course).

Comment: @H2C03 Are you referring to the actual URL itself? The page is about C++, even though the URL seems to imply that it's C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little point in using `BigInteger` if you're going to convert to longs all the time.

You can write that thing using only `BigInteger` operations, in exactly the same way as you would with primitive integers:

```
bool isPalindrome(BigInteger x){
   std::vector<int> digits;
   while (x > 0)
   {
      digits.push_back((x % 10).toInt());
      x /= 10;
   }

   size_t sz = digits.size();
   for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++){
      if (digits[i] != digits[sz - i - 1]){
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: The complier gives me an error at the line `std::vector<int> digits`, what should I include to use this type?

Comment: @moray95 `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
  BigInteger q (static_cast<long>(x - floor(x.toLong()/10)*10));
```

might make the compiler happier. Look inside [BigInteger.hh](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/bigint.git/blob/HEAD:/BigInteger.hh) for the public constructors. Notice that `floor` gives a `double`, hence the substraction gives also a `double`, and `BigInteger` has no constructor for that.

Comment: We're doing C++; use `static_cast`